# What's the best practice for adding an Object to a React hooks (useEffect, useMemo) dependancy array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When you need to add a large object to a react hooks (`useEffect`, `useMemo`, `useCallback`) dependency array, what's the best practice when doing so.

```
let largeDeepObject = {
  parent: {
    child: { ... },
  },
};

useEffect(() => {
  // do something
}, [largeDeepObject]);

const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => {
  // do something
}, [largeDeepObject]);
```

React uses `Object.is()` for array dependency comparison which will return `false` on objects without a reference to the original value. This will re-render the hook even when the object hasn't changed.

```
const foo = { a: 1 };
const bar = { a: 1 };
const sameFoo = foo;
Object.is(foo, foo); // true
Object.is(foo, bar); // false
Object.is(foo, sameFoo); // true
```

Comment: In my experience, you depend on the specific parts of the object you are using.

Comment: You can wrap your object in a `useMemo()` hook so that it only gets recreated when certain props/state change. For all subsequent rerenders where the dependencies for `useMemo()` haven't changed you'll get back the same object reference, so `Object.is()` will return true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best to reference strictly the values that you actually use in the effect, as granular as possible. Many times these will be primitives which means that you don't even have to worry about them unnecessarily changing.

If you do have to reference objects or other structures such as arrays then you need to make sure their reference stays the same. You should always be aware why your references change and prevent this when not necessary. Besides helping your effects work seamlessly it will most probably also positively impact your app performance.

Don't forget to extract your variables outside the component whenever possible (i.e. when not using `props` or `state`). This way you will not need to add them as dependencies.

Also, using memoization up the components chain is always an option (`useMemo`, `useCallback` and soon `useEvent`), just don't overuse it unnecessarily! :)

Comment: So best practice is to go as granular as possible. if needed, keep object references intact.

Comment: Yes, after all if you only use specific properties in your effect it makes sense to only watch for those changes. I don't insinuate it is wrong to watch for extra properties, but it might lead to situations like the one you mentioned and it is not worth the fuss if you don't even need to watch for those extra properties.

More than that, even if you don't have an actual issue with this it might trigger your effects more times than needed because a property you don't care about changed. If you happen to set some state in the effect the component might also unnecessarily re-render.